# Difference between "doesn't seem to rain" & "doesn't seem to be raining"

Tags: grammar, differences, tenses, syntactic-analysis

What's the difference between 'It doesn't seem to rain.'
and 'It doesn't seem to be raining.' ?

Is it that the first means "the rain didn't occur often", and the second means "it doesn't rain in the current moment" ?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please consider visiting the sister stack [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) for queries like this.

Answer (score 1):

Let's bring this to the positive form for sake of simplicity

*It is raining*

And

*It doesn't rain*

The first one is referring strictly to the present while the second one is slightly more vague since it can refer to the moment, an "era" or from the start up until this moment.

Comment: Bringing the statements to the positive might well serve a valid purpose, but wouldn’t you need to state both versions positively, and keep the “does seem to” in both to be able to fully address the OPs question?:
“It does seem to rain.”/”It does seem to be raining.”   That being said, I think your conclusion has merit and, in a roundabout way, might even contain a major part of the answer, so +1.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine this situation, where I have tried to use the two phrases:

Weather Scientists with a central base, around which they have installed many rain-making machines separated by some miles. They press individual buttons to turn on the machines, to make rain around that machine. They are monitoring the machines and the areas, DAILY, for the past 6 months.

---

Scientist 1 : Are all machines working fine ?

Scientist 2 : No; two seem to be malfunctioning.

Scientist 1 : Details ?

Scientist 2 : Well, the machine in Area 8 never worked. I have restarted the machine many times over the past many weeks, but 'it doesn't seem to rain' in that area.

Scientist 1 : What about the other malfunction ?

Scientist 2 : Now, that happened just now. It was working till yesterday, but now I pressed the button for area 34, but 'it doesn't seem to be raining' in that area.

Scientist 1 : Well, send somebody there for further investigation.

Scientist 2 : Sure, I will do that as soon as I finish looking up some "tenses" in this reference {{ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uses_of_English_verb_forms }} ; it will help me write the status report.

---

{{ I am a relative newbie here , so not sure whether this type of answering is suitable for ELU }}